# Scale effect and shadow causing lag when on MapAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am using MapKit to display a custom annotation pin on restaurant locations that are pulled from a database. I have noticed that removing the shadow effect from each of the pins I custom-made as well as the scale effect removes the lag I was experiencing when using the map entirely. Is there anyway to keep the two features but get rid of the lag? Here is the code for the map:

```
            Map(coordinateRegion: $mapViewModel.mapRegion,
                showsUserLocation: true,
                annotationItems: mapViewModel.locations,
                annotationContent: { location in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coords) {
                    LocationMapAnnotationView()
                        .scaleEffect(mapViewModel.mapLocation == location ? 1 : 0.7)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            mapViewModel.showNextLocation(location: location)
                        }
                }
            })

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on other code as well (in your custom annotation view), but try grouping (both, by one, in different places - I cannot test your code, so just idea), because shadow by default affects everything, so if there are a lot of objects might be time consuming; with grouping shadow is applied only to final rendered result, like

```
LocationMapAnnotationView()
    .scaleEffect(mapViewModel.mapLocation == location ? 1 : 0.7)
    .compositingGroup()       // << here !!
    .drawingGroup()           // << here !!
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .onTapGesture {
        mapViewModel.showNextLocation(location: location)
    }
```